# Misleading paper retractions

Tags: retraction

I recently started getting familiar with a non-mainstream physics author who's got interesting ideas. But got some papers retracted with reasons unrelated to the validity of his work.

Is the following a lack of professionalism? should it be called other than retraction?

> Professor Meyl had submitted his work to the Journal of Cell Communication and Signaling clearly stating it was at that time not being considered for publication elsewhere. After thorough investigation the senior editorial team of the Journal of Cell Communication and Signaling must conclude that a similar manuscript was submitted to the journal ‘DNA and Cell Biology’ before the submission to the Journal of Cell Communication and Signaling and that this similar manuscript was still under consideration by ‘DNA and Cell Biology’ at the time of the submission to the Journal of Cell Communication and Signaling. This goes against the policy of the Journal of Cell Communication and Signaling. The Journal of Cell Communication and Signaling will retract this manuscript.
>
> The author has been informed about the reasoning behind the retraction decision and did not agree with the retraction.

[Retraction Note: Meyl, K., 2012: Task of the introns, cell communication explained by field physics, Journal of Cell Communication and Signaling 6 (1), 53–58](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3889249/)

It gives the impression that retracted means wrong, and here, the contents are not being questioned.

Comment: Where does it give the impression that retracted means wrong?

Comment: Yes, it is a retraction, but for reasons of being published elsewhere, not for necessarily being wrong. Publishers don't like to publish already published work. Among other things, there are copyright issues. It is also considered a form of misconduct.

Comment: @TimRias So if you see a paper was retracted, you can't make any conclusion about its veracity... My point is until now I thought Retracting meant the information is lacking in some aspect. as @Buffy said, misconduct doesn't imply the paper is not worth reading. Am I wrong to suggest that `Retracted` would have a negative impact on the audience then?

Comment: Papers are retracted for a variety of reasons. None of them are "good" outcomes for the authors. That retraction notice lays out the journal's reasons quite clearly, and folks can make up their own minds about how that reflects on the author.

Comment: I managed to find one of the 2 articles that were retracted. Having had a look at it I would say it isn't really worth reading since: 1) They claim magnetic monopoles exist (they seem to be referring to quasi-particles in spin glass, doubtful to no relevance for biology), 2) they seem to say there exists resonances that can't couple to detectors (i.e. something that can't be measured), 3) they end their paper with "For this reason, the most
prominent interpersonal resonance will never be measurable,
that is, love."

Comment: The paper also feel incoherent and more like they originally got published because they threw enough physics buzzwords at a biology journal and got through because the reviewers couldn't adequately review the paper at all. So I could believe they took a second look at the paper for some reason and then decided to retract partially because it seemed to slip through  but its easier to retract because it was similar enough to another paper.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the timeline as I see it:

1. You had a preconceived idea that "retraction" means the contents are wrong.
2. You found a retracted paper which has a retraction notice attached to it that clearly explains why the paper is retracted.
3. Now you know that this paper was not retracted because the contents are wrong, and more generally, that "retraction" just means a paper is retracted, by itself it does not tell you why. The same would be true of, say, disqualifications in athletic competitions.

So far, this system seems to be working perfectly to me. The only problem here is you came in with a misunderstanding of what "retraction" means, and thankfully this journal attached a sufficiently informative notice to make your misunderstanding clear, the reason this particular paper was retracted clear, and it's now information you can take forward when you see other retracted papers to be sure you find out why each is retracted if it's important to you. I'd add that [it's not your fault that your misunderstanding needed to be corrected](https://xkcd.com/1053/) - everyone has to learn the things they know someday, and for this particular thing, today was your day - that's good!

I think it's also important to recognize that dual submissions of papers is a very serious offense. At a minimum, it taxes an already strained peer review system and wastes the time of editors and reviewers. It is incredibly rude to do, and retraction is an appropriate response. If I were an editor I'd also consider not accepting further submissions from that author.

Comment: Okay. Objectively I have to admit and accept these statements. Sadly regular people would use the “paper retracted” argument to discredit the author’s ideas, generally without providing counter evidence.

Comment: @juanmf Sure, you might consider that some level of [ad hominem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hominem), but I think it's also important to recognize the level of trust that goes into most academic work. Aside from a mathematical proof where a reader can follow the arguments presented in a paper and make a determination whether the paper is correct, all other papers require that readers trust that the author did what they say they did and that their results are what they say they are. If an author has already shown their ethics are questionable, they may lose that necessary trust.

Comment: Retracted papers are fairly rare. If you routinely use retracted papers in your arguments, then that is something to worry about. The argument in the papers may or may not be wrong, but something was seriously wrong to lead to that retraction.

Comment: Another way to think about it is that the null or base to start from is that the argument in the paper doesn't exist. It's not up to other people to discredit an author or use counter evidence to prove a paper wrong, it's up to the paper's author (or anyone else that wants to use their ideas) to argue convincingly that they are correct. People making non-scientific arguments get this wrong all the time: they make an unsupported statement on Twitter, challenge science to prove them wrong, and think that until someone does a study proving drinking bleach *doesn't* cure COVID it probably does.